# Visual Studio keeps looking for .resx files in the wrong place

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, resx

I am working with visual studio 2012, and my problem occurs in a large, old winforms application solution when I try to compile the whole application (dozens of projects).

When I get the latest code from source control (Team Foundation Server) for the first time, and build the solution, it builds just fine the first time. Then, if I make any changes, a later Build/Rebuild, will sometimes (not always) result in lots of projects in the solution throwing the following error for some of its resx files.

*Unable to create a manifest resource name for "Contracts\Templates\ContractTemplateDb.resx". Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\Contracts\Templates\ContractTemplateDb.vb'*

OR

*Invalid Resx file. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\NeptuneForms\HelpForm.resx'.*

The problem is that there is no reason it should be looking in C:\Windows\system32 for these files, as they exist fine (and did during the last build) in the local directory of the project! The random directory is not always C:\Windows\system32, sometimes it is a random directory of another project, or even in another branch.

This happens sporadically to some of our developers, frequently to others, and almost always to me, and it seems unrelated to the code we are writing, because when it happened, I rolled back all the changes we had made since it started happening, and it still happened.

There are two things I've tried, that had no success.

1. Recreate the entire solution, and remove and readd all resource files as though they never existed before.
2. Install all windows updates and get the latest updates to Visual Studio 2012

Nothing has helped, and I am at a loss. My next step is to upgrade to 2013 and hope for the best, but I'm afraid thats not going to help either.

Does anyone have any similar experience, or any ideas of other things to try? I'm pulling my hair out over this one...

Comment: Open the .vbproj file with a text editor (Notepad is fine) and copy/paste the lines you see that contain "ContractTemplateDb.vb" into your question.

Comment: This is happening to us as well, anyone got a solution?